# how can i implement login with twitter for my jsp/java web project

Tags: java, jsp, twitter, struts1

I have created my project in Struts1(Java framework) . I am using my custom login form for login/authentication purpose. But my Boss wants the user to login with there  Twitter  Account. just like in Stackoverflow.

Same type of login i did for Facebook by calling Facebook Graph Api From json request. But i am confused for twitter login. Even i read the twitter docs [from here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter). Still am confused. Please help me for this.

Comment: i did it by using twitter4j library.. it is easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check my code But you need to obtain ConsumerKey ,ConsumerSectret and accessToken from twitter

```
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;

public class TwitterUtils {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        final String consumerKey = "**********";
        final String consumerSecret = "**********";
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();

        String token = requestToken.getToken();
        String tokenSecret = requestToken.getTokenSecret();
        System.out.println("My token :: " + token);
        System.out.println("My token Secret :: " + tokenSecret);

        //AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token, tokenSecret);
        //twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
        twitter.updateStatus("If you're reading this on Twitter, it worked!");

    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}//main
}/
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be in AsyncTask context

```
final String consumerKey = "**********";
    final String consumerSecret = "*********";


    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, RequestToken>(){
        @Override
        protected RequestToken doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);

                RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
                return requestToken;
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(RequestToken requestToken) {
            super.onPostExecute(requestToken);
            if(requestToken == null)
                return;
            String token = requestToken.getToken();
            String tokenSecret = requestToken.getTokenSecret();
            Log.i("INFO", "My token :: " + token);
            Log.i("INFO", "My token Secret :: " + tokenSecret);
        }
    }.execute();
```