# Twitter login through my application

Tags: java, twitter, web

I've portal created in java, and need user to login through there twitter account.
Information provided on dev.twitter.com is not straight forward and not helpful to me.

I've created application and it is on apps.twitter.com, also generating **KEYS, ACCESS TOKEN**.

OAuth document is not very usefull to me.

Can anyone give me some step by step or something which I can use to go through.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i implement login with twitter for my jsp/java web project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115608/how-can-i-implement-login-with-twitter-for-my-jsp-java-web-project)

Comment: Haseeb, actually I want to do this through javascript so, in future same thing I can use from any platform.[NOT DUPLICATE];-)